# How to show Checkboxes with Fulltext Search Filter Exposed?

Tags: views

I have created a simple search with three filter options of "Contains any of the word", "all of the words" and "none of the word", as shown in the figure below.

I used Search API, and later created a view out of it.

For an exposed filter, I just chose "FullText Search" and exposed it as follows:-

[image]

It shows me a page likes this:-

[image]

Now, it works fine, but I want checkboxes instead of the dropdowns. For that I installed [Better Exposed Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters), but it doesn't show me the option to show checkboxes ... as shown:

[image]

What am I missing that this is not allowing me to show Checkboxes :(. I will be very thankful for your help. I just need to convert them to checkboxes.

Answer (score 1):

Currently BEF doesn't support tweaking the display of the filter operator, only the filter itself. But this would be a great addition -- feel free to post a feature request in the [BEF issue queue](https://drupal.org/project/issues/better_exposed_filters).

Thanks.

Comment: Please note that it is common practice on this site to add some type of disclosure if posting anything about a module for which you are a (co-) maintainer. Something like "Disclosure: I'm the maintainer of BEF". PS: same for various other (interesting) comments you posted.

Comment: I thought the fact I used the same user name on S.O and D.O made it fairly obvious, at least for the folks coming from D.O...

Regardless, your point is valid and I'll try to add a "full disclosure" blurb on post related to modules I maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Normally I would suggest to do a simple form alter and change the type from select list to radio.

But since it looks like you are trying to do it only using modules I would suggest you to take a look at [Dropdown Checkbox module](https://drupal.org/project/dropdown_checkboxes)

> Convert
>
> 1. multiple select lists into dropdown checkboxes
> 2. single select lists into dropdown radio buttons

Comment: Thank you for the assistance. Unfortunately, all I could find was the page to add the ID of <select> dropdown, which it claimed to turn into checkboxes. It didn't work. Am I missing something?